# resizing axes in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a plot where two values on the y-axis are very close together. I would like to add space between to make them more visible, without making the axis itself too large. Is this possible?

MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}[
  width=10cm,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={6.78, 12},
  ytick={-35.81, 0.67, 1.145, 29.59},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={above right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=0,
  xmax=15,
  ymin=-40,
  ymax=40]
 \addplot[thick, blue] plot coordinates {(0,0.67) (6.78, 1.145)};
 \addplot[thick, blue] plot coordinates {(6.78, 1.145) (12, 29.59)};
 \addplot[dotted, blue] plot coordinates {(0,1.145) (6.78, 1.145)};
 \addplot[dotted, blue] plot coordinates {(6.78, 1.145) (0, -35.81)};
 \addplot[dotted, blue] plot coordinates {(6.78, 1.145) (12, 1.51)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Dear invictus, please adapt your MWE so to make it compilable.

Comment: Maybe trying `\begin{axis}[scale=0.75 ... `

Comment: In this case I would either plot the graph in log scale (in this case you will have to give up the negative values) or add a label with the x and y coordinates to the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shift the tick labels at `0.67` and `1.145`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}[
  width=10cm,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={6.78, 12},
  ytick={-35.81, 0.67, 1.145, 29.59},
  yticklabel={%
    \ifdim \tick pt=0.67pt%
        \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}%
    \else 
      \ifdim \tick pt=1.145pt%
        \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}%
      \else
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}%
      \fi
    \fi
  },
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={above right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=0,
  xmax=15,
  ymin=-40,
  ymax=40]
 \addplot[thick, blue] plot coordinates {(0,0.67) (6.78, 1.145)};
 \addplot[thick, blue] plot coordinates {(6.78, 1.145) (12, 29.59)};
 \addplot[dotted, blue] plot coordinates {(0,1.145) (6.78, 1.145)};
 \addplot[dotted, blue] plot coordinates {(6.78, 1.145) (0, -35.81)};
 \addplot[dotted, blue] plot coordinates {(6.78, 1.145) (12, 1.51)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```